# useEffect running on mount causing error and blank object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I keep getting a blank **avatarlistitem** when I click add for the first time and then after that the appropriate item will display after the second click. If I add a new URL and click the third time the item won't appear until the fourth click. I am most likely doing something wrong with my `useEffect` and state values.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import AvatarListItem from './AvatarListItem';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },

    inline: {
        display: 'inline',
    },
    formControl: {
        width: '100%',
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        marginBottom: '50px',
        minWidth: 120,
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        margin: '10px',
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

export default function AvatarList() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
    const [itemDetails, setItemDetails] = useState({});
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resources/products?url=${url}`,
            )
            setItemDetails(result.data[0]);
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [search])


    const addItem = (itemDetails) => {
        const newItems = [...items, itemDetails];
        setItems(newItems);
    };

    let handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(itemDetails);
        addItem(itemDetails);
    };

    let removeItem = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];
        newItems.splice(index, 1);
        setItems(newItems);
    };


    return (
        <div>
            <form className={classes.formControl} onSubmit={e => handleSubmit(e)}>
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Amazon Url" variant="outlined" name='newItem' onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)} value={url} />
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={() => setSearch(url)}>
                    <AddIcon className={classes.extendedIcon} />
                </Button>
            </form>


            <List className={classes.root}>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <>
                        <AvatarListItem
                            itemDetails={item}
                            key={index}
                            index={index}
                            removeItem={removeItem}
                        />
                        <Divider variant="middle" component="li" />
                    </>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Comment: have you checked your useEffect? it only fetch new data on `search` value change. is that your intention? or do you want to fetch data for every change of `item` value?

Comment: i'd like to fetch data everytime a user clicks the add button and append that data to the list of items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better approach may be to purely rely on the `onSubmit` callback instead of relying on the useEffect which may run more often than needed. Also, it doesn't look like you need to use the `search` or `itemDetails` state at all.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import AvatarListItem from './AvatarListItem';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import axios from 'axios';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    },

    inline: {
        display: 'inline',
    },
    formControl: {
        width: '100%',
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        marginBottom: '50px',
        minWidth: 120,
    },
    extendedIcon: {
        margin: '10px',
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

export default function AvatarList() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
    const [items, setItems] = useState([]);


    const addItem = (itemDetails) => {
        const newItems = [...items, itemDetails];
        setItems(newItems);
    };

    let handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const result = await axios(
            `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resources/products?url=${url}`,
        )
        addItem(result.data[0]);
    };

    let removeItem = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];
        newItems.splice(index, 1);
        setItems(newItems);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <form className={classes.formControl} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <TextField id="outlined-basic" label="Amazon Url" variant="outlined" name='newItem' onChange={e => setUrl(e.target.value)} value={url} />
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" type="submit">
                    <AddIcon className={classes.extendedIcon} />
                </Button>
            </form>


            <List className={classes.root}>
                {items.map((item, index) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <AvatarListItem
                            itemDetails={item}
                            key={index}
                            index={index}
                            removeItem={removeItem}
                        />
                        <Divider variant="middle" component="li" />
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </List>
        </div >
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is fetching data every time user click `submit`, based on your `useEffect`, you should not base your `useEffect` on `search` but on `items` itself (as when user submit, you add something to `items`)

your code should look like this

```
   useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                `http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/resources/products?url=${url}`,
            )
            setItemDetails(result.data[0]);
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [items])
```